# How to make my retrofit call appear in recyclerview?

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have a problem making my data from rest api call to appear on my recyclerview. There is no error in build and logcat and it can open in emulator fine without any crash and can showing other functions. It just this part recyclerview is not showing any data from retrofit call. I'm trying many tutorials/solutions but none works.

Here is my JSON data, i want to get the name and the quantity of my stock inventory:

```
13{
"body": [
    {
        "stock_ID": "1004",
        "stock_name": "kobis",
        "stock_quantity": "2"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "1005",
        "stock_name": "bawang",
        "stock_quantity": "2"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "2001",
        "stock_name": "ayam",
        "stock_quantity": "4"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "2003",
        "stock_name": "kambing",
        "stock_quantity": "1"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "3001",
        "stock_name": "kayu manis",
        "stock_quantity": "2"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "3002",
        "stock_name": "lada hitam",
        "stock_quantity": "3"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "4001",
        "stock_name": "minyak",
        "stock_quantity": "1"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "4002",
        "stock_name": "gula",
        "stock_quantity": "5"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "4003",
        "stock_name": "garam",
        "stock_quantity": "5"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "4004",
        "stock_name": "kicap",
        "stock_quantity": "4"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "4005",
        "stock_name": "beras",
        "stock_quantity": "3"
    },
    {
        "stock_ID": "5001",
        "stock_name": "cawan",
        "stock_quantity": "5"
    }
],
"inventoryCount": 13
```

}

My data class (LowStockItem.kt):

```
data class LowStockList(val items: ArrayList<LowStockItem>)
data class LowStockItem(
val stock_ID: String,
val stock_name: String,
val stock_quantity: String,)
```

RestApiService.kt:

```
@GET ("/inventory/read_lowstock.php")
fun getsLowStock(): Call<LowStockList>
```

RestApiInstance.kt

```
    companion object {

    var BASE_URL = "http://roslibiz.com/api/"

    fun getRestApiInstance() : Retrofit {

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

    }
}
```

LowStockAdapter (Recycler View Adapter):

```
class LowStockAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<LowStockAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

var items = ArrayList<LowStockItem>()

fun setListData(data: ArrayList<LowStockItem>) {
    this.items = data
notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): MyViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.low_stock_card, parent, false)

    return MyViewHolder(inflater)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(items[position])
}



class MyViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val nama = view.namaLSrv
    val id = view.idLSrv
    val kuantiti = view.kuantitiLSrv

    fun bind(data: LowStockItem){
        id.text = data.stock_ID
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(data.stock_name)){
            nama.text = data.stock_name
            kuantiti.text = data.stock_quantity
        }else{
            nama.text = "Nama tiada dalam rekod"
            kuantiti.text = "0"
        }
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: LowStockAdapter
private fun setupRV(){
    lowStockRV.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
        recyclerViewAdapter = LowStockAdapter()
        adapter = recyclerViewAdapter

        val decoration = DividerItemDecoration(applicationContext, VERTICAL)
        addItemDecoration(decoration)
}
    private fun getLowStock(){

    val retroInstance = RestApiInstance.getRestApiInstance().create(RestApiService::class.java)
    val call = retroInstance.getsLowStock()

    call.enqueue(object: retrofit2.Callback<LowStockList>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<LowStockList>, response: Response<LowStockList>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                recyclerViewAdapter.setListData(response.body()?.items!!)
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<LowStockList>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Masalah untuk mendapatkan data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
}
```

I'm at my wit end and needs help from other perspectives. Thank you in advance.

EDIT.
this is what i get from debugging and honestly i dont know what to do.

```
02/24 15:04:25: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 XL API 30.
Install successfully finished in 688 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.roslibusiness/com.example.roslibusiness.ui.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.roslibusiness.test | com.example.roslibusiness
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.roslibusiness.test | com.example.roslibusiness
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.roslibusiness.test | com.example.roslibusiness
Connecting to com.example.roslibusiness
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:63581', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/e.roslibusines: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/e.roslibusines: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/e.roslibusines: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.roslibusiness is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
    waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10153(com.example.roslibusiness) identical 5 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1362)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
    Installing application
    VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/e.roslibusines: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.roslibusines: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;I)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/e.roslibusines: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10153; state: ENABLED
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xea4a3c50, tid 7992
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xea483f10: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea483f10: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xbbc39170) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xea483d50, tid 7992
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
    allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fbc17000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1136ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=9582448914498, Vsync=9582548914494, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=9582554363800, AnimationStart=9582555337800, PerformTraversalsStart=9582555413300, DrawStart=9583238424100, SyncQueued=9583494447900, SyncStart=9583496712300, IssueDrawCommandsStart=9583496796500, SwapBuffers=9583584814100, FrameCompleted=9583588012900, DequeueBufferDuration=571700, QueueBufferDuration=1002300, GpuCompleted=8029250115450508212, 
I/Choreographer: Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

EDIT: what should i do with this error?

```
E/Retrofit Error: retrofit2.DefaultCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@ccab847
```

Comment: well, debug it.  have you placed a breakpoint in this line : `recyclerViewAdapter.setListData(response.body()?.items!!)`  ? do you know if data is returned from your api call ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody i get this but i dont know what to do about it?

Comment: Your json objects are only having two properties but in data class you are trying to access one more property val stock_ID: String. In your onRespose function can you log response.body() and see what response you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the definition of your function `setListData`

Currently it is this

```
fun setListData(data: ArrayList<LowStockItem>) {
    this.items = data
}
```

It should be changed to

```
fun setListData(data: ArrayList<LowStockItem>) {
    this.items = data
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

This is a better way of notifying the adapter from within the class.

notifyDataSetChanged() notifies your adapter that data has been changed for use by the RecyclerView, and hence the adapter looks at the new data, and inflates it accordingly.

Also make sure that you are passing the correct data in the adapter.

The retrofit data that you have posted above does not contain the ID field, as declared by you in the class. It might throw some error in that case. As you are in Kotlin, you can use the Android Studio feature to directly convert your json data into an object class, this would help you to create exactly what needs to be used for the successful deserialization. This Android Studio feature is known as `Kotlin data class file from JSON` and can be found under File -> New.

Comment: OP is already doing `recyclerViewAdapter.setListData(response.body()?.items!!)
                recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so i doubt this will make a difference

Comment: Yeah, it could be added in the adapter itself.

I think the response from Retrofit is not right, or maybe the conversion is not right. 
I suggest you use StethoInterceptor to intercept and analyse your API calls.

Comment: sure, but it won't make the code work any differently, so it doesn't really answer the question, right ?

Comment: thank you, it kinda works because at least i get feedback from this line 

override fun onFailure(call: Call<LowStockList>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Masalah untuk mendapatkan data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

at least i know the problem from the connection with retrofit

Comment: @PriyanshKedia i will try looking at the stethointercepptor. i have a feeling that the type of data I'm passing is incorrect. do you know how can i identify which data passing is correct. tq in advance

Comment: You can either print the data that you are passing and check if according to that.
As you are passing the list, maybe the problem lies with the conversion of your API response to the object

Answer (score 0):

Problem would be with assigning new instance of `List` to items, when adapter is holding the different reference, add `response` to existing list instead of reassigning instance

```
fun setListData(data: ArrayList<LowStockItem>) {
    this.items.clear()
    this.items.addAll(data) 
}
```

Comment: can you clarify a bit? i dont quite understand the last part "add response to existing list instead of reassigning instance"

Comment: when you create instance of items, it will be passed as data source to adapter, adapter now uses that instance to check for changes in data, now when you do `this.items = data`, you are pointing items to reference, so adapter would not know about that source, hence it is be better to update the list instead of assigning it to `data`